# Extract Sender address email from MeetingItems/ReportItems

Tags: python, email, outlook, office-automation, sender

I'm trying to write a program that finds my e-mails. I'm having trouble writing a function that would return the sender's email address. Whatever type of message it is.
I find function:

```
def return_sender(msg):
    if msg.Class == 43
        if msg.SenderEmailType == "EX":
            if msg.Sender.GetExchangeUser() != None:
                return msg.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress
            else:
                return msg.Sender.GetExchangeDistributionList().PrimarySmtpAddress
        else:
            return msg.SenderEmailAddress
```

Class 43 is MailItem, but for example how to get the sender's address from class 53 = MeetingItem?

```
msg.Sender
```

It returns AttributeError.

```
msg.SenderEmailAddress
```

It returns:

```
/O=EXCHANGELABS/OU=EXCHANGEADMINISTRATIVEGROUP(FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=6F467C825619482293F429C0BDE6F1DB-
```

Is there any way to get the sender from a message type other than MailItem? And how you can check outlook what type of message is
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert an Exchange formatted X509 email address into SMTP one. Read more about that in the [HowTo: Convert Exchange-based email address into SMTP email address](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2009/05/08/outlook-exchange-email-address-smtp/) article.

Here is one of the possible ways:

```
/// <summary> 
/// Finds the SMTP addres based on an exchange string inside an outlook contact 
/// </summary> 
/// <param name="">Has to be an exchange address string</param> 
/// <returns></returns> 
private string GetSMTPAddressViaOutlookObjectModel(string exchangeAddress) 
{ 
    // Start with an empty string 
    var address = string.Empty; 
 
    // Create a recipients with the exchange address 
    // E.g. ..... 
    Outlook.Recipient recipient = Module.OutlookApp.Session.CreateRecipient(exchangeAddress); 
 
    // Resolve the recipient 
    recipient.Resolve(); 
 
    // When the recipient is resolved 
    if (recipient.Resolved) 
    { 
        // Get the user behind the resolved address 
        Outlook.ExchangeUser user = recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser(); 
 
        // If the user is found 
        if (user != null) 
        { 
            // set the address to the primary SMTP address of the exchange user 
            address = user.PrimarySmtpAddress; 
            // Release the user object 
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(user); 
        } 
 
        // Release the recipient object 
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(recipient); 
    } 
 
    // return the address 
    return address; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve any MAPI property using `ReportItem/MeetingItem.PropetyAccessor.GetProperty`, you just need to know the property's DASL name. E.g. `PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_SMTP_ADDRESS` (may or may not be available on a particular item) is `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x5D02001F"`. Take a look at the report/meeting item with [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author) - select the item in question, click IMessage button on the OutlookSpy ribbon, select the property you need, look at the DASL edit box.